# MYSQL JOIN ON table1.table2_ids IN tabel2.id

Tags: mysql

**table1**

```
+----+------------+
| id | table2_ids |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 1,2,3      |
+----+------------+
```

**table2**

```
+----+------------+
| id | some_col   |
+----+------------+
| 1  | some_col   |
| 2  | some_col   |
| 3  | some_col   |
+----+------------+
```

I want to get `table1` with `table2` where table2's id in table1's table2_ids
like A post with three images, and post just have images's id, I need return images's url.

I think it will be:

```
select * from table1 join table2 ON table2.id IN table1.table2_ids
```

but it's wrong.

Thanks so much

Comment: Do not store foreign keys in csv format. Normalize your tables

Comment: Do you want to return result if ANY matchs or if ALL match?

Comment: @Jens I know it's a ugly struct ,but It has been there with large data ,I can't change it

Comment: Please adjust your question in order to present the tables' data in a more readable and formally right way. Also, please be more specifical with the type of data you are working with. A more specifical title could be helpful too for people that find your question among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of data you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

```
select * from Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t2.id,t1.tbl2_id)
```

More Info : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 a, tabl2 b where a.id=b.id
```

Comment: table A has comma separated values and b has one value. Will your join comparison work?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

More correct in your case will be

```
select * 
from table1 
join table2 ON 
  POSITION(
    CONCAT(",", table2.id, ",") IN 
    CONCAT(",", table1.table2_ids, ",")
  ) > 0
```

but such database structure is not good, you should separate it in 3 tables

table1, table2 and intermediate table table3 which will connect them

table3 will have fields table1Id, table2Id